# Identifying missclassified pixels in random forest classifier python sklearn

Tags: python, random-forest

I have a dataframe that contains 10 predictors (PCA from Landsat Data).
The data is loaded as pandas dataframe and it contains in addition to predictors, also x_coor and y_coor information for every pixel. Then I split my dataframe into test and training dataset using the built-in sklearn modules for this. But when I have to fit the model I have to set the predictors, and a class label column for that (X,Y). I have to ignore (delete) the x_coor and y_coor for every pixel. If someone sticked with me at this point.

Is there a way after making the prediction to retrieve from the original dataframe all observations that were missclassified, including the x_coor and y_coor information to locate them in a GIS package?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: To check out results QGIS 3.16

Comment: Are you asking how to use pandas dataframes with PyQGIS In a Python script?

Comment: I would convert your dataframe to a geodataframe in geopandas. Then use your geodataframe to sample the random forest predictions. From there, you can compare which pixel values from your training set differ from the predicted values within the geodataframe using pandas tools. Or, depending upon how you coded the RF, join the predicted output to your geodataframe and do the comparison.

Comment: @Aaron I could follow your recommendation!. I just used numpy and pandas tools to check the false predicted values and create a numpy array with the index in the original dataset. From the original dataset I got from the columns x and y coordinate the coordinate information, and using geopandas tools I transformed this information as a WKT and created the geometry column and exported it as a vector in ESRI Shapefile Format.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve the problem. Please consider adding your comment as an answer so we can consider this question resolved.